# Source Tree not highlighting currently branch

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

[image]

When I double click on the branch to checkout it does not highlight the current branch. I've reinstalled, removed from registry, and still will not highlight current branch. Any information what be helpful thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your graph ? If you open the terminal and execute "$git status" what do you get?

Comment: Well that's the thing if I use the terminal I can see that what current branch I'm using. I'm just trying to use sourcetree.